# Delete file while another process still writes to it

Tags: python, file, io

I'm playing around with writing to file with Python:

```
import time

fo = open("foo.txt", "a+", 1)

while True:
    fo.write("Some data to write"); 
    time.sleep(.001)
```

If I execute this code, and than just manualy delete the "foo.txt" file, the process still writes somewhere.

What happens with the content? The process writes to file, but no file is available.

Comment: What platform are you on? On OS X the content will just disappear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `The Linux Programming Interface` by Michael Kerrisk

> In addition to maintaining a link count for each i-node, the kernel also counts open file descriptions for the file (see Figure 5-2, on page 95). If the last link to a file is removed and any processes hold open descriptors referring to the file, the file won’t actually be deleted until all of the descriptors are closed.

Your script have opened the file, thus it holds a open descriptor referring to the file. System won't delete the file just after you have removed it by i.e. use of `rm` command. But it will delete it after your script close the descriptor.

I have found reference in man, from `man remove`:

> remove() deletes a name from the filesystem.  It calls unlink(2) for files, and rmdir(2) for directories.
>
> If the removed name was the last link to a file and no processes have the  file  open,  the  file  is deleted and the space it was using is made available for reuse.
>
> If  the  name  was the last link to a file, but any processes still have the file open, the file will remain in existence until the last file descriptor referring to it is closed.

Just as @oglu mentioned in his answer, this is not portable behavior. On Windows, you may chose whether it should be possible to remove the file that you have opened.

From [CreateFile function at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> FILE_SHARE_DELETE (0x00000004)
>
> Enables subsequent open operations on a file or device to request delete access.
>
> Otherwise, other processes cannot open the file or device if they request delete access.
>
> If this flag is not specified, but the file or device has been opened for delete access, the function fails.
>
> Note  Delete access allows both delete and rename operations.

Comment: Just tested it. The file removed with no problems

Comment: Could you explain how did you test it? The rm command will remove the file from directory, but the linux kernel will maintain the /unnamed/ file as long as there is a possibility to write to or read from it. And there is, from your script. When your script ends, there is no more such a possibility and kernel will do the cleaning

Comment: @luantkow If `rm foo.txt` while `python foo.py` is running, the file is removed (`ls` doesn't show the file `foo.txt` anymore). But do you mean that the actual data on the dist are deleted only after the the `foo.py` terminates? Is it this also the reason why Linux can update without rebooting? For example, if a `file` (which can be a  script) needs to be update, while it is already running, we can `delete` the old one, and `replace` with the new one?

Comment: @adosar I am not sure if you mix foo.txt and foo.py by mistake or not. If this is a mistake, as long as python has open descriptor to a foo.py, it would be safe to do so. I don't think that software like python would close and reopen file with the script that they currently running, but I have never checked that. Empirical test confirms that script continues to run on Python 3.8.10.

Comment: @luantkow The script `foo.py` opens the file `foo.txt` and writes by using user's input. What I did is `rm foo.txt` while the `foo.py` was running (asking users for text). `ls` while `foo.py` was still running didn't show `foo.txt`.

Comment: @adosar ls did not show foo.txt, because that file is no longer in that directory. It does not mean that the file does not exist in filesystem. For your previous question: Yes, that behavior allows user to replace executable with new version while old is still running. Yet you would need to restart the script to start using new version.

Answer (score 1):

The actual question is what happens when a file descriptor is changed while writing, which is platform specific.

If you have a POSIX system, the FD remains open until the last consumer closes it, in which case the content cannot be accessed (the file is already unlinked).

If you have a windows system, I think you can't delete the file while it's being written (exclusive access).

Comment: The question is not about if content can be accessed. But what happens with the content being written, if no file exists. HOW can a process write to a not existing file?

Comment: Forget for a moment about the file. You are not writing to a file, you are writing to a file descriptor. As long as the file descriptor is open, you can keep writing on it.

Comment: Also, as a note (in posix systems), even if you delete a file (unlink) this file exists until the last fd to the file is closed. After it's closed the file disappears and the storage can be reused. In other words, the file exists even if its name does not exist, up until the point where all the fds to that file are closed.